# Блоки налезли на блоки Flexbox

Tags: css

Почему товары 4-5-6 налезли на верхние товары 1-2-3? Всего 6 товаров.

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.product:hover .product-hide {
  display: block;
}

.product-box {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 20px;
}

.product-show {}

.product-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 1</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 2</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 3</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 4</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 5</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-show">Товар 6</div>
      <div class="product-hide">Купить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>https://jsfiddle.net/zmyhz9hd/</sub>

Comment: Подскажет кто нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что высота товаров равна 0, вот 4-5-6 стали вверху слева.
Задайте для `.product` высоту, и блоки станут снизу.

Comment: Необходимо чтобы была динамическая высота, как сделать?

Comment: Если по простому, нужно по другому сверстать. Если нужно в существующую верстку вклинить, тогда можна так:
https://jsfiddle.net/zmyhz9hd/2/
`position: absolute` в `.product-box` убивает высоту, по етому блоки и наплывают друг на друга

Comment: Можете показать пример правильной верстки? необходимо чтобы при :hover блоки не дергались

Comment: тогда нужно чтобы надпись купить была невидимой а не скритой
https://jsfiddle.net/zmyhz9hd/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zmyhz9hd/4/

Comment: От пустого пространства как избавиться?

Comment: https://www.technodom.kz/ - Вот как у них на сайте, как сделать? При наведении невидимые блоки появляются, без использования height?

Comment: у них на сайте нет невидимых блоков, просто бордер для карточки при ховере

Comment: Ну это для примера, не суть) Подскажите как мне решить мою проблему?

Comment: Проблема решается просто или фиксировать карточки по высоте, тогда  можна прятать что то внутри карточки без потерь, или ничего не прятать, тогда все карточки будут одной высоты. Нельзя сделать одно без другого. Есть разные пути решения, оба в примерах выше, с каким идти дальше решать вам.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно такой вариант поможет

```
.products {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .product {
      position: relative;
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      height: 100px;
    }
    .product:hover .product-hide {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .product-box {
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .product-show {}
    .product-hide {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```